# Hotel reservation for a couple applying for Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, hotels

I'm travelling to Amsterdam and Paris with my girlfriend. We made the hotel reservation in Amsterdam under my name, and the Paris hotel reservation under hers. But in both the reservations, there's no way to add a second guest name. We both have the Schengen Visa appointment in London at the Netherlands embassy, on the same day in consecutive slots. Would the immigration officers be okay with this?

We have all other bookings, such as flights, train, other tours and trips under our respective names.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This should be ok.

I have applied Shengen visa with only my name and they didn't ask anything.

You can include a cover letter explaining the purpose, stay and itinerary to be on the safer side.